# i have 2 tables owner(Name,ID int) Property(PID int,Name(fk) references Owner). List Owners who have one property

Tags: javascript, database, oracle, stored-procedures, database-trigger

```
SQL> SELECT
  2  Owner_First-name,Owner_Last-name,Owner-ID
  3  FROM Owner
  4  INNER JOIN(SELECT
  5  Owner-ID, COUNT(*) AS Count Of
  6  FROM Property
  7  HAVING COUNT(*)>1
  8  )Ow ON Owner.Owner_First-name AND `Owner.OwnerID`=Property.OwnerID
  9  );
)Ow ON Owner.Owner_Firstname AND Owner.OwnerID=Property.OwnerID
                         *
```

> ERROR at line 8:
>
> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: You seem to be using oracle, not mysql. I modified the tag of your question accordingly.

Comment: Do you really have dashes (`-`) in your column names (like `Owner_First-name`), or it's a typo?

Comment: Owner_First-name,Owner_Last-name,Owner-ID - what is that "-" doing there?

Comment: In order to get better answers, you should add an actual question in you question.

Comment: I understand that you are a new contributor and as such you may also be new to SQL. However, you haven't asked a question and your SQL has some very basic syntax issues in that you have included '-' in the variable names. I think when asking a question it would be good to do perhaps a tiny bit of an attempt at research first.

Comment: stack overflow could not appload my document when i wrote Owner_Firstname so i changed it, in my code i wrote Owner_Firstname

Answer (score 0):

You have  wrong columns alias  (for composite name use backtics )
don't use minus for column name (or if you use wrap the full name with backtics )
and you have wrong code repetition and improper join ..
you use alias Ow for subquery then you should use the related  table name alias in join

```
SELECT Owner_Firstname, Owner_Lastname, OwnerID
FROM Owner
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT OwnerID, COUNT(*) AS Count_Of
  FROM Property
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1
  ) Ow ON  Owner.OwnerID=Ow.OwnerID
```